# Gnuplot - transparent surface plot without lines

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a **transparent** surface using pseudofile `'++'` (gnuplot 5.2):

```
set isosample 100
set style fill transparent solid 0.65 
splot [0:5][0:5] '++' u 1:2:(sin($1)*sin($2)) w pm3d
```

but it results in a plot with both lines around each tile of the surface.

[image: gnuplot result]

I am not sure how to make these transparent as the tiles, or how to suppress them altogether. Using the `noborder` or any `border` option of `set style fill` does not seem to change the output at all.

EDIT: The problem is actually terminal dependent.

- above plot is with the `qt` terminal using its built in export
- `png`, `jpg` and `gif` have lines :
  [image]

But if exported as vector graphics (`svg` or `pdf`), again the screen rendering will depend on the viewer used (okular no lines, acrobat reader 9 has them), with [some renderers having no lines: check here how your browser behaves](https://www-liphy.ujf-grenoble.fr/pagesperso/etienne/stackoverflow_gnuplot.svg) (firefox, chromium, epiphany on my linux box are all line-free)

Output of `show pm3d`:

```
pm3d style is explicit (draw pm3d surface according to style)
pm3d plotted at SURFACE
taking scans direction automatically
subsequent scans with different nb of pts are flushed from BEGIN
flushing triangles are not drawn
clipping: all 4 points of the quadrangle in x,y ranges
pm3d quadrangles will have no border
steps for bilinear interpolation: 1,1
quadrangle color according to averaged 4 corners
```

Comment: could you post your entire script? just to make sure that there are no "conflicting" settings, etc. (the command in the snippet `splot [0:2][0:2]` does not seem to correspond to the plotted range)...

Comment: @ewcz: this is the entire script, sorry I'd changed the range for the image just to get a nicer output. Updated.

Comment: It looks to me that the pm3d border linetype has been set to -6.  That is not the default, so I am not sure where or how it happened.  You can explicitly disable the border with `set pm3d noborder`.   Either way you can check this with `show pm3d`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it doesn't change things. However, it pointed me in the direction of a problem with the terminal... see answer.